# intermittent 500 response to asynch calls from web client for servicestack service running on iis

Tags: asp.net, rest, iis-7, servicestack, http-error

I have RESTful services running that are getting some strange intermittent 500 errors that are really generic when being called asynchronously from the webclient. Trying to figure out what may be causing the issues.

Note:

- When the API gets a request message, it tries to validate a token
  through another service call to an endpoint at
  "/Security/AG/v1/token".
- This may take several seconds as you can see from the filtered IIS
  logs included.
- This token verification service talks to a nosql db as well as a sql
  server db to validate the token.
- When it finishes, the parent service will then continue with it's
  logic if it is a successful validation, format a message response and
  sends it back to the web client.

Somehow it sends back some 500 errors that I can't seem to pinpoint. By default, I have try catches that send appropriate error codes in the message response with stack traces when there is a server error.

Sure would like to see if anyone has any ideas where I may look.
Could it be a request timeout? Unlikely since the IIS default is to "keepalive" for about 2 mins I believe.

IIS log data (these are the 500 errors that have been logged): uri | time | millisecs

- /Security/AG/v1/token                                     4:50:14 PM  21593
- /Mighty/xxxx/problems/528f6c42072ef708ecd43f59    4:50:14 PM  21655
- /Security/AG/v1/token                                     4:57:07 PM  19156
- /Mighty/xxxx/problems/528f6c42072ef708ecd43f59    4:57:07 PM  19218
- /Security/AG/v1/token                                     5:11:02 PM  19171
- /Mighty/xxxx/cohorts/                                     5:11:02 PM  19218

PS - these calls eventually succeed. Since the browser seems to send several calls repeatedly for the idempotent calls. I just want to know where the 500s might coming from and why.

Technology stack: IIS7, ASP.NET, Servicestackv3, C#, mongodb, sserver, Chrome